# html5 input type datetime value not showing on ASP.NET webform

Tags: asp.net, html, input, webforms

*Edit* 
I have an Asp.Net FormView, with an itemtemplate:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateStart" SortExpression="DateStart">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEditStageDetailsDateStart" type="datetime-local" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# Bind("DateStart") %>' CssClass="TextBoxDateTime"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateStart") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle Width="160px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

When the Form is in View Mode, the date is correctly showed (of course when the date is set):

[image]

However, when the Form change in Edit Mode, the input with type="datetime-local" is showed **but** is ***empty***, requiring the user to choose a *new* date. This is the **Popup** showed:

[image]

However, as I can see inspecting the generated html source, the **value** is correctly set...

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$StageDetailsView$TextBoxEditStageDetailsDateStart" value="28/05/2013 10:00:00" id="MainContent_StageDetailsView_TextBoxEditStageDetailsDateStart" class="TextBoxDateTime" type="datetime-local" style="width:160px;">
```

So two problems:
first is that in Edit mode, I am not able to see what the actual value is;
second if I only want to change the day or hour I have to re-enter the whole date...

My question is: Is this the Html5 planned behaviour or I am missing something?

Comment: For me, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I first tested it on IE and I got no issues. Then I tried it on Chrome and understood what you meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local.attrs.value):

> **value** = local date and time
>
> A string representing a local date and time. The following parts, **in
>   exactly the following order**:
>
> - A date.
> - The literal string "T".
> - A time.
>
> Example:
>
> 1985-04-12T23:20:50.52
>
> 1996-12-19T16:39:57

So, in your case:

```
value="2013-05-28T10:00:00"
```

will work.

**[UPDATE]**

You may use the following `aspx` markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateStart" SortExpression="DateStart">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEditStageDetailsDateStart" type="datetime-local" runat="server"
            Text='<%# GetFormattedDate(Eval("DateStart")) %>' CssClass="TextBoxDateTime"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateStart") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ControlStyle Width="160px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In your code behind, define the following method:

```
protected string GetFormattedDate(object dateTimeObject)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeObject.ToString(), out dateTime))
    {
        return String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}T{3}:{4}:{5}",
            dateTime.Year,
            dateTime.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'),
            dateTime.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'),
            dateTime.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'),
            dateTime.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'),
            dateTime.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
            );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works perfect for showing the date ...
but now I don't know how to Bind it (the Update doesn't do nothing)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the problem is that the HTML parser wants a Date formatted in the ISO 8601 standard.

Without the need to use a Custom format function in code behind, I ended up with this declarative markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEditStageDetailsDateStart" type="datetime-local" runat="server"
Text='<%# Bind("DateStart", "{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}") %>' CssClass="TextBoxDateTime"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This is the standard format 's': https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Sortable so you could just use {0:s}